# awk adding a semicolon if empty

Tags: awk

I do have a file with different length of each line. E.g.:

```
a; 1; 2; 3; 4;  
b; 11; 22;  
c; 122; 233; 344; 45; 56;  
d; 13;  
e; 144; 25; 36; 47; 58; 69;
```

I try to generate a file, separated by semicolon where each line has the same amount of values. E.g.:

```
a; 1; 2; 3; 4; ; ;  
b; 11; 22; ; ; ; ;  
c; 122; 233; 344; 45; 56; ;  
d; 13; ; ; ; ; ;  
e; 144; 25; 36; 47; 58; 69;
```

I tried different ways with awk but I am to newbie to get it done correctly in bulk.

```bash
awk '{if( $4 == ""){print ";"}else{print $4}}' testtest.txt
```

I hope the swarm intelligence can help me with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making your records contain at least 8 fields:

```bash
awk -F '; *' -v OFS='; ' '{$8 = $8} 1'
```

---

**limitations:**

- The wanted number of fields is specified **statically**, so you need to already know how many there are in the input file (see @RavinderSingh13 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74611118/3387716) for a generic way to determine the number of fields).
- If, for example, there's a record with **9** fields, the code will **not** strip it down to **8**.

Answer (score 6):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. This is more a like Generic code, where I am getting highest number of fields in whole Input_file in its first read and then once its found passing it to 2nd Input_file and assigning NF value for each line to NF value which gives total number of fields as per need and puts `;`  for fields newly added.

```bash
awk -v FS='; ' -v OFS='; ' '
FNR==NR{
  nf=(nf>NF?nf:NF)
  next
}
{
  $nf=$nf
}
1
'  Input_file  Input_file
```

Comment: NOTE: I am passing Input_file 2 times into the `awk` code.

Answer (score 3):

@RavinderSingh13's answer works but requires that the input file name be repeated in the argument list, which can be avoided by modifying `ARGC` and `ARGV`:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="; "
}
NR==1{
  ARGV[ARGC++] = FILENAME
}
FNR==NR{
  nf=(nf>NF?nf:NF)
  next
}
{
  NF=nf
}
1
' testtest.txt
```

Comment: Don't do the `ARGV[ARGC++] = FILENAME` in the body of the script or `NR==1` will have to be tested for every input line which is an unnecessary performance hit (and a bit more code), just do `ARGV[ARGC++] = ARGV[1]` in the `BEGIN` section instead.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
>      gawk 'BEGIN { FS = (OFS = "; ") "*" } NF = 8'
> -or-
>      mawk NF=8 FS='; *' OFS='; '
> ```

```
a; 1; 2; 3; 4; ; ; 
b; 11; 22; ; ; ; ; 
c; 122; 233; 344; 45; 56; ; 
d; 13; ; ; ; ; ; 
e; 144; 25; 36; 47; 58; 69;
```